# Can't Open URL in Safari in UI5 app in Cordova Container

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sapui5

I have developed an SAPUI5 app that works on browser, and I am trying to make it an iOS build by wrapping it in a Cordova container.

In one of the pages of the app, I defined a button that when it is clicked, it should open up a separate Safari window (see code below), however, when I test this functionality, it opens the URL directly in the application.

Therefore, if I want to go back to the home page of the app, I need to kill the app and restart it.

I have this same problem with and without the inappbrowser Cordova plugin.

Does anyone have any ideas of a possible resolutions for this? Appreciate the help!!

```
var button= new sap.m.Button ({icon: "sap-icon://meal"
                              , press: function (oEvent) 
                              {window.open ('MYURLHERE', '_system')}})
```

Comment: Are you calling "window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;" first?  Without that, it will not override that functionality and you will be navigating to a blank page without the cordova scripts, resulting in a blank page.

Comment: The standard window.open() JavaScript method cannot be used to open a new tab and window from a global HTML file -- by Apple